# Textbook Proposition on Product of Real Analytic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

> Let
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j (x-c)^j && \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty b_j (x-c)^j \\
> \end{align*}
>
> be two power series with intervals of convergence $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ centered on at $c$. Let $f_1(x)$ be the function defined by the first series on $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $f_2(x)$ the function defined by the second series on $\mathcal{C}_2$. Then, on their common domain $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}_1 \cap \mathcal{C}_2$, it holds that
>   \begin{align*}
>   f(x) \cdot g(x) &= \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{j+k=m} (a_j \cdot b_k) (x-c)^m \\
> \end{align*}
>
> **Proof**: Let
>   \begin{align*}
>   A_N &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^N a_j (x-c)^j & B_N &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^N b_j (x-c)^j \\
> \end{align*}
>
> be respectively, the Nth partial sums of the power series that define $f$ and $g$. Let
>   \begin{align*}
>   D_N &= \sum\limits_{m=0}^N \sum\limits_{j+k=m} (a_j \cdot b_k) (x-c)^m &  
>   R_N &= \sum\limits_{j=N+1}^\infty b_j (x-c)^j \\
> \end{align*}
>
> We have:
>   \begin{align*}
>   D_N &= a_0 B_N + a_1 (x-c) B_{N-1} + \cdots + a_N (x-c)^N B_0 \\
>   &= a_0 (g(x) - R_N) + a_1 (x-c) (g(x) - R_{N-1}) + \cdots + a_N (x-c)^N (g(x) - R_0) \\
> \end{align*}
>   [snip]

I've transcribed the above from my Real Analysis textbook and stopped at the part I'm having trouble understanding. How do you get from the first definition of $D_N$ to the second one? They seem like different equations. I've tried to do sequence manipulations to get from one definition to the other, but I've not had success.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Author: Krantz. Title: Real Analysis and Foundations. Proposition 9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with the first representation of $D_n$ and obtain the  second one.

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_n}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=0}^N\left(\sum_{{j+k=m}\atop{j,k\geq 0}} a_jb_k\right)(x-c)^m}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^N\left(\sum_{j=0}^m a_jb_{m-j}\right)(x-c)^m\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq j\leq m\leq N}  a_jb_{m-j}(x-c)^m\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^N\sum_{m=j}^N  a_jb_{m-j}(x-c)^m\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^Na_j\sum_{m=0}^{N-j}b_m(x-c)^{m+j}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^N a_j(x-c)^j\sum_{m=0}^{N-j}b_m(x-c)^m\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^N a_j(x-c)^jB_{N-j}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   and we finally got the second representation of $D_n$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we eliminate $k$ by substituting $k\to m-j$.
- In (2) we write the index region somewhat more conveniently.
- In (3) we exchange the order of summation.
- In (4) we shift the index $m$ to start with $m=0$.
- In (5) we factor out the terms which are not dependent on $m$.

> We also obtain for $0\leq j\leq N$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{g(x)}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(x-c)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{N-j} b_k(x-c)^k+\sum_{k=N-j+1}^\infty b_k(x-c)^k\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=B_{N-j}+R_{N-j}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the last line of OP's post follows from (6) by replacing $B_{N-j}=g(x)-R_{N-j}$.

Comment: Amazing. Except that I believe that (3) should start with $\sum_{j=0}^N$ rather than $\sum_{m=0}^N$

Comment: @clay: You're welcome. Typo corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually prove this by induction

> Works for $N = 1$

\begin{eqnarray}
D_1 &=& a_0b_0 + (a_0b_1 + a_1 b_0)(x - c) \\ &=& a_0 [b_0 + b_1(x - c)] + a_1[b_0(x - c)] \\
&=& a_0 B_1 + a_1 B_0
\end{eqnarray}

> Assume that it works for $N - 1$

$$
\sum_{m = 0}^{N - 1}\sum_{j + k = m}a_j b_k(x - c)^m = a_0 B_{N - 1}
+ a_1(x - c) B_{N - 2}  + \cdots + a_{N-1}(x - c)^{N-1}B_0 \tag{1}
$$

> Now let's prove it for $N$

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{m = 0}^{N}\sum_{j + k = m}a_j b_k(x - c)^m &=& \sum_{m = 0}^{N - 1} \sum_{j + k = m}a_j b_k(x - c)^m + \sum_{j + k = N}a_j b_k(x - c)^N \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& a_0 B_{N - 1}
+ a_1(x - c) B_{N - 2}  + \cdots + a_{N-1}(x - c)^{N-1}B_0 \\
&& + [a_0 b_N + a_1 b_{N - 1} + \cdots + a_N b_0](x - c)^N \\
&=& a_0 \left[ B_{N - 1} + b_N(x - c)^N \right] + a_1(x - c) \left[ B_{N - 2} + b_{N - 1}(x - c)^{N -  1} \right] \\
&& + \cdots + a_{N}(x - c)^{N}[b_0] \\
&=&a_0 B_N + a_1(x - c) B_{N - 1} + \cdots + a_{N}(x - c)^{N}B_0 \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!